# Match centroids from one dataset with polygons of another

Tags: r, spatial-join, sf, centroids

I want to make a data frame showing which voting precincts are in each school zone. To do this, I want to see which precincts' center points are in which school zones.

```
library(sf)

precincts <- st_read("voting_precincts.shp")
precincts$centroid <- st_centroid(
  x = precincts
)

elemZones <- read_sf("school_zones.shp")
```

So although I have the centroid coordinates for precincts, I do not know how to "join" them with the school zones data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the few limitations simple feature standard for geometries has is that it cannot have two geometry columns; you may have two or more columns with WKT definitions but you have to decide which column to use. In your case you try to add the centroid as a column, but what `sf` does is to add a the whole `sf tbl` object (the data frame) as a column, if you print the object with `str(precincts)` you'll see the classes of each column, if you just print `str(precincts$centroid)` you'll get:

```
 str(precincts$centroid)
 Classes ‘sf’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame'
```

`st_centroid` will return a whole `sf tbl`, so you may just do:

```
 library(sf)
 library(dplyr)
 precincts <- st_read("voting_precincts.shp")
 elemZones <- read_sf("school_zones.shp")

 st_centroid(precincts) %>% st_join(elemZones)
```

Comment: Worked great. Side note I noticed I used `st_read()` and `read_sf()`. That was by mistake. But is there a difference between the two functions?

Comment: `read_sf`  and `write_sf` are aliases for `st_read` and `st_write`, respectively, with some modified default arguments. `read_sf` and `write_sf` are quiet by default: they do not print information about the data source. `read_sf` returns an `sf-tibble` rather than an  `sf-data.frame`. `write_sf` delete layers by default: it overwrites existing files without asking or warning. (from the `sf` package reference)